# send picture + text in iMessage in ios programatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms

is there any possibility to send picture + text in iMessage in ios programatically?

if it is possible can anyone help me?

Comment: This might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170516/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-ios7-addattachmentdatatypeidentifierfilename-n

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it , its same like doing for mail just do this

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>

MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123456789"];   // your recipient number  or self for testing
picker.body = @"test from OS4";
NSData*imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"]];
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG   filename:@"image.png"];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```