# Take screenshot and send it programmatically

Tags: ios, sms, screenshot, mms

When a user taps on a button in my app, I'd like to take a screenshot of the current view and open up a text message with that screenshot image as an attachment. How can I do this in iOS7?

(I've seen posts on how to take a screenshot but not anything on taking a screenshot and attaching it to a message)

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170516/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-ios7-addattachmentdatatypeidentifierfilename-n

Comment: To take screenshot you can use `Quartz Display Services` i.e either `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect` or `CGDisplayCreateImage`

Comment: is your issue sending a screen shot as an MMS ? have you coded for capturing screen shot?

Comment: I'm able to take a screenshot but I would like to automatically attach it to an MMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** For taking a screenshot add the `QuartzCore` framework,  you can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 ); //you can use PNG too
```

**2.** For attaching this image in mail, add `MessageUI` framework in build phase. And use this `NSData` for attaching, something like this

```
//Check if mail can be sent
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

       // Add NSData you got as screenshot to attachment
       [mailer addAttachmentData:theImageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.jpg"]];  
        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

    }
```

**EDIT:**

**3.** Sending image through SMS

```
    // Will Work only for iOS 7

    MFMessageComposeViewController* messageComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
     messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self; // As mentioned by the OP in comments, we have to set messageComposeDelegate to self.
     messageComposer.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123456789"];

 if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
  {

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendAttachments)] && [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments])
    {
        NSString* uti = (NSString*)kUTTypeMessage;
        [messageComposer addAttachmentData:theImageData typeIdentifier:uti filename:@"filename.jpg"];
    }

    [self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Handle the delegate callbacks from `MFMessageComposeViewController`

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{

}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but I really need to do this via text messaging (SMS/MMS). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @shikaka, please check the edit. One problem is this is available only from iOS 7. And haven't tested it on device. Sorry about that

Comment: Amazing job. 2 more questions: 1 - How do I exit the MMS compose view once I'm done? It freezes? 2 - It doesn't take a screenshot of the entire screen. The navigation bar is left out of the photo and there is a strange whitespace at the bottom. Do you know why?

Comment: @shikaka. To exit the MMS compose view controller, you have to implement the delegate method `- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result;` in here you give `    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`. This is called when cancel/done is tapped or if any error.

Comment: @shikaka, for second question i'm not really sure, sorry. Maybe you can try  `UIWindow *window =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow];UIView *viewForScreen = window.viewForBaselineLayout;`, not sure if it works

Comment: the modal still isn't dismissed, even after I implemented the delegate method, and added < MFMessageComposeViewControllerModal > to the interface. Any thoughts?

Comment: @shikaka Hmm you should add `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` in `.m` , and use `messageComposer.delegate = self;`. After that implement the delegate method, you get callback for type `MessageComposeResult`, which has three options   `MessageComposeResultCancelled, MessageComposeResultSent, MessageComposeResultFailed`. See if this helps ?

Comment: thanks again. The thing that solved it (and you might want to edit your terrific answer) is that you need to set     `messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

To take the ScreenShot you can use `Quartz Display Services` methods

You can pass the rect as

```
CGRect = [self bounds];
```

Then create image using `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect`

```
CGImageRef selectedScreenImage;
selectedScreenImage = CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(kCGDirectMainDisplay, rect);
```

Convert it to `NSData`

```
NSData *data = (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(selectedScreenImage)));
```

And then Attach it to your message using `MFMailComposeViewController`

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *cvc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        cvc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

       [cvc addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"]];  

        [self presentModalViewController:cvc animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a MMS

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromViewIniOS7
{
UIImage* image = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentScrollview.contentSize);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = contentScrollview.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = contentScrollview.frame;

    contentScrollview.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    contentScrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentScrollview.contentSize.width, contentScrollview.contentSize.height);
    if ([[NSString versionofiOS] intValue]>=7)
    {
        [contentScrollview drawViewHierarchyInRect:contentScrollview.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        [contentScrollview.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    }
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    contentScrollview.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    contentScrollview.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


return image;
}
-(void)buttonAction
{
MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]; 
pasteboard.persistent = YES;
pasteboard.image = [self imageFromViewIniOS7];

NSString *phoneToCall = @"sms:";
NSString *phoneToCallEncoded = [phoneToCall stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneToCallEncoded];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];    

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
NSMutableString *emailBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Email Body"];
picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123456789"];
[picker setBody:emailBody];// your recipient number or self for testing
picker.body = emailBody;
NSLog(@"Picker -- %@",picker.body);
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
NSLog(@"SMS fired");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to do this without needing to paste? Just automatically having the image in the text message?