# send audio with MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

does anyone know i this is possible by doing something like

```
[compose addAttachmentData:data typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeAudio filename:@"test"];
```

The resulting message isn't of any playable format so not sure if its possible at all? The data file does play in an audio player so I know thats correct.

Thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the filename to include a proper file extension, e.g. @"test.caf", instead of just @"test". See this answer for a similar question: 
[MFMessageComposeViewController iOS7 addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170516/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-ios7-addattachmentdatatypeidentifierfilename-n)